# How to configure acpi for battery?

Tags: 10.10, kernel, battery, acpi

I am using:

```
acpitool -B
```

to print out information about my battery. It returns:

```
  Battery status : <not available>
```

When I do ls in /proc/acpi/battery, there are no files.

A few other modules print out "" like fan and thermal. But then there are some modules (such as cpu) that print out just fine. So is there some kind of script I need to run to generate the BAT0 file in there or do I need to create and configure it manually?

This is on Ubuntu 10.10. I am using kernel version 2.6.35-32-generic-pae. The machine is actually a robot custom built so I don't think I have of the problems seen with Toshiba, Asus, etc. Shouldn't the main concern be the type of battery I am using and the kernel version?

When I do

```
grep ACPI /boot/config-2.6.35-32-generic-pae
```

I get the following output:

```
# Power management and ACPI options
CONFIG_ACPI=y
CONFIG_ACPI_SLEEP=y
CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS=y
CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER=y
CONFIG_ACPI_POWER_METER=m
CONFIG_ACPI_SYSFS_POWER=y
CONFIG_ACPI_PROC_EVENT=y
CONFIG_ACPI_AC=y
CONFIG_ACPI_BATTERY=y
CONFIG_ACPI_BUTTON=y
CONFIG_ACPI_VIDEO=m
CONFIG_ACPI_FAN=y
CONFIG_ACPI_DOCK=y
CONFIG_ACPI_PROCESSOR=y
CONFIG_ACPI_HOTPLUG_CPU=y
CONFIG_ACPI_PROCESSOR_AGGREGATOR=m
CONFIG_ACPI_THERMAL=y
CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_DSDT_FILE=""
# CONFIG_ACPI_CUSTOM_DSDT is not set
CONFIG_ACPI_BLACKLIST_YEAR=2000
# CONFIG_ACPI_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_ACPI_PCI_SLOT=y
CONFIG_ACPI_CONTAINER=y
CONFIG_ACPI_SBS=y
CONFIG_ACPI_HED=m
CONFIG_ACPI_APEI=y
CONFIG_ACPI_APEI_GHES=m
CONFIG_ACPI_APEI_EINJ=m
CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ=y
CONFIG_X86_POWERNOW_K7_ACPI=y
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI=m
CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI_IBM=m
CONFIG_PNPACPI=y
CONFIG_ATA_ACPI=y
CONFIG_PATA_ACPI=y
# ACPI drivers
# ACPI drivers
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI=m
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_ALSA_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_DEBUGFACILITIES=y
# CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_UNSAFE_LEDS is not set
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_VIDEO=y
CONFIG_THINKPAD_ACPI_HOTKEY_POLL=y
CONFIG_ACPI_WMI=y
# CONFIG_ACPI_ASUS is not set
CONFIG_ACPI_TOSHIBA=m
CONFIG_ACPI_CMPC=m
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please add information (brand and model) about the computer or laptop you are using.

Comment: Hi, I added some info about that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This Might Help

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_make_ACPI_work

see if it works and if it did dont forget to press Answered :P
enjoy :P

Comment: Hi, I went there but none of the info helped. ACPI is already enabled in my kernel.